# The source of "close" are different from security('60',close) of 20m and close of 60m

Tags: pine-script

the code on 20m chart

```
// © david03kimo

//@version=4
study("MTM close")
hclose=security(syminfo.ticker, '60',close)
plot(hclose)
```

the code on 60m chart

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © david03kimo

//@version=4
study("MTM close")

plot(close)
```

and the result output to graph,I can check the close price is not consistency.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OovFa.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

That's because the close you are seeing on the 60m chart at the 11:00 bar is the close at 12:00, which hasn't occurred yet [on bars earlier than <strike>at</strike>] 11:40 on the 20m bars, so that bar is showing the last confirmed close, i.e., the one of the 10:00 bar which closed at 11:00.

#### Version 2

While the edited version 1 of the answer is now correct, it wasn't the problem in your screenshot as it was showing an 11:40 bar. There is another issue, which is your use of `syminfo.ticker` (which used the generic ticker, in this case `FX:GBPCHF` rather than `syminfo.tickerid` which uses the chart's ticker).

This code shows the difference:

```
//@version=4
study("MTM close", "", true)
hclose=security(syminfo.ticker, '60',close)
hclose1=security("FX:GBPCHF", '60',close)
hclose2=security(syminfo.tickerid, '60',close)
plot(hclose)
plot(hclose1)
plot(hclose2)
```

You'll see `hclose` and `hclose1` being always equal, whereas `hclose2` will show what you expect.

Comment: I found the difference just now.If I change to other charts, it matches.I think it's because of some market data's issues. as to bar close,If I want the bar close at 12:00,I have to choose 20m 11:40 and 60m 11:00 to close at 12:00 together,I think.

Comment: Edited my answer. We're making progress! Sry for the confusion.